# How do i manage ever increasing number of images in gatsby

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-image

I am trying to build a website that has around 13 images for just the background and socials but even more images on just 1 page. they are 30 images on just one page.

how do i manage more images using Gatsby statically because background images don't need to be dynamic.
(no graphql)

A gist of how many images i need to put statically;
[image: A gist of how many images i need to put statically]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way to add images in Gatsby is to [import them directly into files](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/images-and-media/importing-assets-into-files/), and I think that this would work well with your use case.

If this doesn't work for you, you can also [use the static folder](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/images-and-media/static-folder/).

For more, refer to Gatsby's docs, there's an entire section on [Adding Images and Media](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/images-and-media/).